# Does $\cos(n^2)/n^2+5$ diverge or converge?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

In my opinion it converges by comparison test... but I am not sure. Also I was trying ratio test where I have got $\cos (1)=1$ and that's why it is converge

Comment: Whats your interval of interest?

Comment: Are you talking about a series or a sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it converges since its absolute value is bounded by ${1\over{n^2+5}}$ which converges towards zero, so it converges towards zero.

Comment: Does this work both for series and sequences?

Comment: yes, since the serie $\sum{1\over{n^2+5}}$ converges.

Comment: Yes but i was thinking what if it was a sequence...?

Comment: it converges towards zero.

Comment: Yup..that is the thing!